# Rails Form: save first form, then redirect to a second or third form with the params of the first form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm new to rails and I'm trying to create a form in two parts. First, you fill in the user form. Then you choose to become a prestataire or a employeur. And by clicking on the respective button, the user form will be saved, and you will be redirected either to the prestataire's form or the employeur's with the recently created user params.

Until now, I didn't manage to send the recently created user params, only saving and redirecting. But then I get this error in the prestataire_controller, since prestataire belong to user. The error is similar when I click on the employeur button:

```
def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) #This is where there's an error. 
    @prestataire = @user.build_prestataire
  end
```

Here is the code I've written so far:

User Form:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :civility, 'Titre de civilité: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :civility %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :forename, 'Prénom: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :forename %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :surname, 'Nom de famille: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :surname %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email, 'Email: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password, 'Mot de passe: ' %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password, size: 40 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, 'Confirmation de mot de passe: ' %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, size: 40 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :phone, 'Numéro de téléphone: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :phone %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Employeur', name: 'employeur' %>
    <%= f.submit 'Prestataire', name: 'user_id' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

User controller:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        if params[:commit] == 'employeur'
        format.html { redirect_to new_employeur_path, notice: "Renseignez vos informations d'employeur" }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
        else 
        format.html { redirect_to new_prestataire_path, notice: "Renseignez vos informations de prestataire" }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
        end
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to new_employeur_path, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

private
  def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :surname, :forename, :civility, :phone, :employeur)
  end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :prestataire
  has_one :employeur
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :password, :forename, :surname, :phone, :civility, presence: true
  validates :password, confirmation: true
  has_secure_password
end
```

Prestataire model:

```
class Prestataire < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :projets, as: :projetable
  has_many :employeurs, through: :projets
  has_many :offres, through: :projets
  has_many :feedbacks, through: :projets
  validates :siren, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates_associated :users
end
```

Routes file:

```
Workplace::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :prestataires
  resources :employeurs
  resources :projets
  resources :feedbacks
  resources :offres
  root 'projets#index'
```

I was thinking about adding an *onclik* option on the f.submit and adding an adequate method. But I read somewhere that f.submit was not the best option for this kind of request, but no other suggestion was made. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can we see the error? And if it's related to the route then the routes file for these controllers.

Comment: Maybe I should add a CurrentUser Module and register the user information before it is loaded into the database with f.submit?...

Comment: The error is: Couldn't find User without an ID

Comment: I think your approach is fine. Saving info into the user and then creating a role (prestatair or employeur) is great! See my answer for help on getting things working in this fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it makes sense that a Prestatair should be nested under a User. But your routes file does not do any nesting yet. I would recommend to nest the routes as such:

```
resources :users do
  resources :prestataires
  resources :employeurs
end
```

After doing this, `@user = User.find(params[:user_id])` should work... but you may also see other issues at that point that you'll have to fix. The reason that line will work now lies in the fact that you will now have that `params[:user_id]` present in the params hash, as provided by the nested :users routes. For more...

Use `bundle exec rake routes` to see what routes and named_route name the above nesting creates and update your code accordingly.

Comment: The error is now different indeed: undefined local variable or method `user' for #<UsersController:0x00000004885b40>. And it seems to come from this mistake:         format.html { redirect_to new_prestataire_path(user_id: user), notice: "Renseignez vos informations de prestataire" }

Comment: Event if I delete (user_id: user), there's the same error.